# Is there a DM script command controlling the STEM image raster rotation during continuous image acquisitions?

Tags: hardware, dm-script

I want to write a DM script for acquiring STEM images continuously with DigiScan, accompanied with the changing of raster rotation angles of individual STEM images by, for example, 10 degrees for each frame.

I am currently writing a DM script as follows:

```
Number paramID

Number width     = 512 // pixels
Number height    = 512 // pixels
Number rotation  = 0   // degrees
Number pixelTime = 3.2 // microseconds
Number lSynch = 0

paramID = DSCreateParameters( width, height, rotation, pixelTime, lSynch )

Number signalIndex = 0
Number dataDepth = 4 // bytes
Number selected = 1
Number dataDepth

Image dsImage
Number imageID

dsImage := IntegerImage( DSGetSignalName( signalIndex ), dataDepth, 0, width, height )
dsImage.ShowImage( )
imageID = dsImage.GetImageID( )

DSSetParametersSignal( paramID, signalIndex, dataDepth, selected, imageID )

Number continuous = 0
Number synchronous = 1 - continuous
Number nFrame = 10

while( iFrame < nFrame ){
    DSStartAcquisition( paramID, continuous, synchronous )
    DSwaitUntilFinished( )

    // How to rotate STEM images here?
}

dsImage.DeleteImage( )
DSDeleteParameters( paramID )
```

However, I'm not sure how to modify the script to increase the raster rotation angle by 10 degrees after each frame acquisition is completed during continuous imaging.

I know the command to control the raster rotation angle, but I'm unsure if there's a way to change the angle during continuous acquisition.

If anyone has any knowledge in this area, I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. A rotation change (-also via the UI-) initiates a new scan with the DigiScan.